# Can you open/edit a sharepoint 2010 workflow in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

I have a site that has been migrated from SP2010 to SP2013. It has a list with a SP2010 workflow associated with it. Is there anyway I can open it to see what it does? The original site has gone so can't revert back to that.

Thanks

Comment: I believe it should open seamlessly using SPD 2013. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, you should be a able to open the workflow with Sharepoint Designer 2013.

Comment: When I click on it, it just opens the site list's associated workflows page. I want to open it for editing in SPD2013 to see what it is doing

Comment: you can view this site for more information http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-2013/migrating-sharepoint-workflows-2010-2013-and-beyond

Comment: That was no help whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

Source - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chandru/archive/2013/04/14/upgrading-spd-2010-workflows-to-spd-2013-workflows.aspx

The SharePoint 2010 Workflow platform has been carried forward to SharePoint Server 2013. SharePoint designer 2010 workflows will be upgraded as it is in SharePoint 2013 but will run in SharePoint 2010 workflow platform. All of your workflows that were built by using SharePoint Server 2010 will continue to work in SharePoint Server 2013.  There are two platforms (2010 and 2013) available to choose from when you build a workflow in SharePoint Server 2013 provided you had installed and configured Workflow Manager.

If you want your 2010 SPD workflows to run in 2013 platform, then you have to recreate the workflow as the assemblies and runtime are different now in SP2013. Also, there is a change from XOML to XAML format. The activities which are implementations of activity classes, are implemented declaratively by using XAML.

The other option to run SharePoint 2010 workflows on SharePoint 2013 platform is to use SharePoint workflow Interop which enables SharePoint 2010 workflows (which are built on Windows Workflow Foundation 3) to be called from SharePoint 2013 workflows (which are based on Windows Workflow Foundation 4) . This allows you to execute 2010 workflows from within 2013 workflows.  Here is the Microsoft SP Designer team blog about triggering a SharePoint 2010 workflow from a SharePoint 2013 workflow

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/08/18/how-to-trigger-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-from-a-sharepoint-2013-workflow.aspx

Comment: It's been upgraded I want to open it for editing in SPD2013

Comment: What error you are getting when you try to open in 2013?

Comment: no error, clicking on the associated workflows in the list area just opens up up the list in the site on the associated workflows page. The workflow itself does not appear in the workflow area of SPD2013

Comment: Can you try to open it using SPD2010?

Comment: The same behaviour in SPD2010. The workflow does not appear in the workflow area in SPD. It does appear in the Associated Workflows in the list area when I click on it in there it opens the lists associated workflows on the site.

Comment: Did you move the whole content database when you upgraded? I lost all my workflows when i upgraded to SharePoint 2013.. Or to be more precise, the workflows were intact but lost it's associations to the lists.

Comment: I didn't upgrade it. The workflow is working fine. I just want to make a change to it and cannot find anywhere to open it.

Comment: Extra - There is a SP2013 workflow associated with a content type that's associated with the list which calls the SPD2010 workflow and it all works fine.