# "Please select a workflow template" message when trying to update the workflow settings (approvers) in SP 2013

Tags: workflow

We have upgraded from SP 2010 to SP 2013 & everything works fine except one issue.

we are not able to modify existing approval workflows to change the approvers, when we select the existing 2010 workflow from workflow settings page, it opens the workflow page to change the settings but no workflow template selected & if we still try to click on next it gives message "please select a workflow template".

I don't understand why workflow template is unselected ? all the workflow features are already activated & I don't want to reactivate the workflow features because there are in-progress workflows and I don't want to  loose them.

Please let  me know if anyone has any idea how to fix this.

[image: Detailed ScreenShots]

Comment: you maybe found your answar here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136071/can-you-open-edit-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Thanks Milad, but this will not solve my issue. I have attached the screenshot  to give more idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's been long time, but just wanted post temporary workaround I had.

Use IE developer tools to change a workflow templates list attribute (remove ”disabled” attribute), this will enabled the selection of workflow template & will allow us to access the second page and make the alterations necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some changes and republish the workflow.

Comment: It is out of the box approval workflow, how could I make changes and republish?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I enabled out of the box workflows on a site, I opened document approval workflow in SPD and tried to associate it to a list. It was opening the browser and after clicking next it was saying 'please select a template'.

I then published the workflow in SPD and it worked.